# If condition inside of map() React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning reactjs and I want to change the color of a badge component depending on the value of a record that I call from the database through an API. However, when I try to do this it shows me nothing when I run it, do you know what I am missing or how I can do it?

```
<tbody>
  {this.state.SociosData.map((e, key) => {
    return (
      <tr className="trTable">
        <td>
          <b>{e.nombre_tienda}</b>{" "}
          <p className="mt-3  ">
            {e.id_tienda} | {e.tipo_tienda} | Area {e.area_tienda}
          </p>
          <p>{e.direccion_tienda}</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          {() => {
            if (e.estatusfirma_tienda === "Aprobado") {
              return <Badge bg="success">Firmado</Badge>;
            } else if (e.estatusfirma_tienda === "Rechazado") {
              return <Badge bg="danger">Firmado</Badge>;
            } else {
              return <Badge bg="warning">Firmado</Badge>;
            }
          }}
          {() => {
            if (e.estadolinea_tienda === "Activo") {
              return <Badge bg="success">Activo</Badge>;
            } else {
              return (
                <Badge bg="light" text="dark">
                  Inactivo
                </Badge>
              );
            }
          }}
        </td>
        <ModalFirma></ModalFirma>
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are running you're if statement as a function. As @Nicholas Tower mentioned you would have to wrap it and invoke it.

I would make a ternary operator in your badge prop that will check the status and change accordingly.

```
<Badge bg={e.estatusfirma_tienda === 'Aprobado' ? 'success' : e.estatusfirma_tienda === 'Rechazado' ? 'danger' : 'warning'}>Firmado</Badge>
```

I tested it myself and confirm this works.

Answer (score 1):

```
{() => {
  if (e.estatusfirma_tienda === "Aprobado") {
    return <Badge bg="success">Firmado</Badge>;
  } else if (e.estatusfirma_tienda === "Rechazado") {
     return <Badge bg="danger">Firmado</Badge>;
  } else {
     return <Badge bg="warning">Firmado</Badge>;
  }
}}
```

If you want to use a function to embed `if` statements in the middle of your jsx, you need to wrap it in parentheses and then call the function. This makes it a case of an "[immediately invoked function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)", or IIFE:

```
{(() => {
  if (e.estatusfirma_tienda === "Aprobado") {
    return <Badge bg="success">Firmado</Badge>;
  } else if (e.estatusfirma_tienda === "Rechazado") {
     return <Badge bg="danger">Firmado</Badge>;
  } else {
     return <Badge bg="warning">Firmado</Badge>;
  }
})()}
```

But it's more common in react to see this done with [ternary expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), so i would recommend instead doing something like this:

```
{e.estatusfirma_tienda === "Aprobado" ? (
  <Badge bg="success">Firmado</Badge>
) : e.estatusfirma_tienda === "Rechazado" ? (
  <Badge bg="danger">Firmado</Badge>
) : (
  <Badge bg="warning">Firmado</Badge>
)}
```